# All of a sudden, Webapp2 cannot be found by python interpreter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, aptana3

I'm running the latest Python 2.7 and Google App Engine SDK on Windows.  Everything is working fine until tonight, now python is throwing import errors about webapp2 in every app I have and all local projects are returning blank pages.

I've seen all the posts about the path, etc but its not working.  I installed Bluestacks the other day and I think that POS did something.  I've done several uninstall and reinstalls of everything python related to no avail.

Here is my path string if it helps

(User PATH)

> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;D:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\

(System PATH)

> C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\iCLS      Client\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\AMD
>   APP\BIN\X86_64;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\AMD APP\BIN\X86;C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS LIVE;C:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS
>   LIVE;%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32;%SYSTEMROOT%;%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WBEM;%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;D:\PROGRAM
>   FILES\ATI TECHNOLOGIES\ATI.ACE\CORE-STATIC;C:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\WINDOWS LIVE\SHARED;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON
>   FILES\INTUIT\QBPOSSDKRUNTIME;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\GOOGLE\GOOGLE APPS
>   SYNC\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\GOOGLE\GOOGLE APPS MIGRATION\;C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES\COMMON FILES\NEATRECEIPTS\DRIVERS\M12\;D:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\GOOGLE\GOOGLE_APPENGINE\;D:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\GOOGLE\GOOGLE_APPENGINE\LIB\;;D:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\QUICKTIME\QTSYSTEM\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL
>   SDK\3.0\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

I created a PYTHONPATH variable:

> D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib;

The error I get when running anything in Aptana or the command line:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Python
>   Files\Udacity Python\Blog\Blog\main.py", line 17, in 
>       import webapp2 ImportError: No module named webapp2

Could there be Environmental variables GAE sets that I'm missing now?  Please help, I'm at my wits end.

Thanks!

***Update***

In response to jacek2v, the output is

> C:\Python27>python "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver .py"
>   "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Python Files\Udacity Python\blog\blog\main.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 1 97, in
>   
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 1 93, in
>   _run_file
>       execfile(script_path, globals_)   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
>   vappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 872, in 
>       main()   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
>   vappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 865, in main
>       dev_server.start(options)   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
>   vappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 657, in start
>       options.yaml_files)   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
>   vappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 549, in **init**
>       module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(yaml_path)   File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
>   vappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 82, in **init**
>       self._yaml_path)   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
>   vappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 266, in
>   _parse_configuration
>       return appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)   File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appi
>   nfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
>       appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)   File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appi nfo.py", line
>   1756, in LoadSingleAppInfo
>       listener.Parse(app_info)   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml
>   _listener.py", line 226, in Parse
>       self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))   File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml
>   _listener.py", line 172, in _HandleEvents
>       for event in events:   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml
>   _listener.py", line 212, in _GenerateEventParameters
>       raise yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError(e) google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: mapping
>   values are not allowed here   in "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Python
>   Files\Udacity Python\blog\blog\main.py", line 19 , column 42

This is a simple program that outputs one line. Here is the main.py file

> import webapp2
>
> class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): ***THIS is line 19, column 42 per the error above, I omitted the comments above it for clarity.
>
> ```
> def get(self):
>     self.response.write('Bloogggger')
> ```
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>       ('/', MainHandler),('/', Blog, '/'),('/blog/', newpost ) ], debug=True)

Here is the app.yaml  ***Its properly formatted and indented in the file, i can't get it to paste properly here

> application: wpablog2014 
>   version: 1 
>   runtime: python27 
>   api_version: 1
>   threadsafe: yes
>
> handlers:
>   - url: /favicon.ico
>     static_files: favicon.ico
>     upload: favicon.ico
>
> - url: .*
>     script: main.app
>
> libraries:
>   - name: webapp2
>     version: "2.5.2"

Comment: Could you add the results of `python --version`?

Comment: Let's start to fix command line. Try to start your app from command line: path_to_python\python.exe full_path_to_google_appengine\dev_appserver.py full_path_to_your_project What is result?

Comment: jarondl, the python version is 2.7.6.  jacek2v, I added what you requested into the question.  Thanks

Comment: OP says it was a configuration issue, reinstalling Python cleared it up.  I voted to close this.

Answer (score 1):

`raise yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError(e)`

Your problem is on the `app.yaml` file:

Your **mistake** is here, the syntax is wrong. the `-` goes to next line indented by 2 spaces:

```
handlers: - url: /favicon.ico #wrong
static_files: favicon.ico #wrong
upload: favicon.ico #wrong

url: .*
script: main.app#wrong
libraries: - name: webapp2 #very wrong
version: "2.5.2" #wrong
```

correct example:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

The syntaxt in the app.yaml file is strict. Please read [here](http://yaml.org/refcard.html) about it's syntax and **[here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig)** for the app engine config.

Btw when having a problem try to read the logs for keywords. The log is your friend.

Comment: Like I had noted above, the YAML file is formatted correctly, I could not get it to copy and paste correctly with the blockquotes.  This happens across all my projects so its not just this file unfortunately.

Comment: @Delecron the errors state clearly that start when reading the app.yaml from your app configuration. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is definately a configuration issue.  Multiple apps and overnight none of them work, some that haven't been touched in weeks.  I'm going to z out the machine and try again.  Thanks all.

Comment: I wiped the python installation and started over.